# How to check if string exists in template?

Tags: python, templates, zope, template-tal, zpt

I'm returning a string `body_class` to my view. I can't seem to put in a condition without breaking it:

```
<body tal:condition="body_class" class="${body_class}">
<body tal:condition="not body_class">
```

Kinda works. It outputs the body class but the rest of the template doesn't work. I'm looking for a solution that puts in the body class if the string exists, otherwise leaves it out.

Dunno what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your talking about a browser view (BorwserView).

Something like that should work if body_class is a method of your BrowserView:

```
<body tal:condition="view/body_class" class="${view/body_class}">
...
</body>
<body tal:condition="not: view/body_class">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Don't think I'm using that. In my views function I `return {body_class: 'my class'}`, and that's what I'm trying to check the existence of.

Comment: If possible, I'd like to avoid having 2 instances of the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `tal:condition` here; you are toggling the *whole element* on or off, including the contents.

You only want to set the class attribute:

```
<body tal:attributes="class: body_class">
```

This works fine for empty strings, you'll just get an empty `class` element; if `body_class` is `None`, the attribute will be omitted altogether.